# Java method in Coldfusion gives double the correct answer

Tags: java, coldfusion, lucee

Well, I partly answered the question.  The commas that I thought were separators in the list we being counted as part of the string.  So the question becomes -- is there a better way to set up a Java list?

Here is the code:

```
<cfset objString = CreateObject(
"java",
"java.lang.String"
).Init(
    JavaCast(
        "string",
        "s,s,s,n,n,n"
        )
    )
/>

<cfset objString = objString.lastIndexOf('n') />

<cfoutput>
#objString#
</cfoutput>
```

The answer should be 5 but I get 10.  Every other answer is also doubled, both with this method and the IndexOf() method. Can someone tell me how to fix this (besides dividing my answer by 2) and/or what is going on?

The lastIndexOf() method is working in generic ColdFusion without any Java code.  But I am trying to convert that code to Lucee, which does not recognize the lastIndexOf() method.  The above code works in Lucee exactly as in Coldfusion -- that is it is giving me double the correct answer.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm actually trying to do exactly what the example shows:  find the position of the last occurence of a letter in a list.  It's part of a more complicated program.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting that result, but you could reverse the string then use listFind to find the position and then subtract that from the listLen to get the position.

Comment: Just to clarify, there really is no special "list" type in CF. It is just a plain old string. The java method `String.lastIndexOf()` simply sees a bunch characters and searches for the one you specified. It knows nothing about delimiters. So 10 *is* the correct answer here. If you need the individual characters to be treated as discrete elements, you must either stick to CF's "list" functions OR use some sort of array object (ie what java calls a ["List"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html)).

Comment: Why are you casting anything. Just use the string, reverse it and use listFind.

Comment: Leigh,  Yes, I had deduced what you say, but don't know enough about Java to make the fix.  Beginner's answer below provides that info.

Comment: Leeish,  that is a good idea -- didn't think of it.

Comment: @BettyMock - Gotcha. Just wanted to clarify *why* it was happening. Beginner's answer is a good explanation of how it might be done with java. That said, I agree with Matt and Leeish on this one. Though there is no native "lastIndex" type function, you could easily roll your own with native CF functions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting double the results as the `comma(,)` are counted as well because the list has been passed as a string.

[`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class has a constructor that accepts a `char array` i.e., [`String(char[] value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(char[])) so, you can try this:

```
<!--- Comma delimited list --->
<cfset local.myList = "s,s,s,n,n,n">

<!--- Convert list to array --->
<cfset local.myCharArray = listToArray(local.myList, ",")>

<!--- Create String object using String(char[] value) contructor --->
<cfset local.objString = createObject(
                            "java",
                            "java.lang.String"
                         ).init( 
                              javaCast( "char[]", local.myCharArray )
                           )>

<!--- Get last index --->
<cfset local.lastIndex = local.objString.lastIndexOf('n') />

<!--- Output: 5 --->
<cfoutput>#local.lastIndex#</cfoutput>
```

Here is the [`TryCF`](http://trycf.com/gist/5eeb197fe97016f133a0a0dd552ea2b8/acf2016?theme=monokai).

Another approach using [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for working with list of `string`:

```
<!--- Comma delimited list --->
<cfset local.myList = "s,s,s,no,not,no">

<!--- Convert list to array --->
<cfset local.myCharArray = listToArray(local.myList, ",")>

<!--- Create ArrayList Object --->
<cfset local.objArrayList = createObject(
                                "java",
                                "java.util.ArrayList"
                            ).init( 
                                javaCast( "int", arrayLen(local.myCharArray) ) )>

<!--- Add item(s) --->
<cfset local.objArrayList.addAll(local.myCharArray)>

<!--- Get last index --->
<cfset local.lastIndex = local.objArrayList.lastIndexOf("no") />

<cfoutput>#local.lastIndex#</cfoutput>
```

Here is the [`TryCF`](http://trycf.com/gist/f5dfed5d3649cf7a2ad1666568d0762a/acf2016?theme=monokai).

Comment: Both of these work fine, and provide exactly the info I needed.